# solveset/solve 4th order polynomial roots

Tags: python, sympy

I am experimenting with sympy and got an unexpected result when trying to solve the 4th order polynomial `x**4+b*x+c=0` which reduces to `x**4-1=0` when `b=0,c=-1`, its roots being `{−1,1,−,}`. Yet this is what I am getting from python3.8.1:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
from sympy import __version__ as sympy_version
sympy_version
>>'1.6.2'
x,b,c,r,r1,e,e1=symbols('x,b,c,r,r1,e,e1')
e=sympify('x**4+b*x+c')
r=solveset(e,'x')
e1=e.subs({b:0,c:-1})
r1=solveset(e1)
r.subs({b:0,c:-1}),r1
>>({0}, {−1,1,−,})
```

Why solving the general equation and then substituting the values for b and c fails? What I am doing wrong?

I get the same results with `python 2.7.5 sympy 0.7.6.1` and the [online sympy system](https://live.sympy.org/).

Comment: Isn't the answer correct? Zero is a solution.

Comment: I suspect that the quartic formula does not work if the equation can be reduced to something else. In this case, when b is 0, the quartic formula can be reduced to a linear equation in `x**4`. I believe that sympy implicitly assumes b!=0 when applying the quartic formula. It should probably return a piecewise. It already does so for c!=0. But for more general cases, the piecewise expression would become insanely complicated.

Comment: Putting `b=0` gives `0/0` type problems in the formula which isn't valid at precisely `b=0`. The correct answer is found by taking the limit as `b->0` e.g. `{ri.subs(c, -1).limit(b, 0) for ri in r}`.

Comment: @Maelstrom, thank you. I implemented in python the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) formulae. The general formula is not valid in this particular case as S is 0. S appears in the denominator, a `ZeroDivisionError` should occur but it didn't, probably due to rounding errors.  I agree with you that a piecewise expression for S expressed in terms of the polynomial coefficients would be extremely complicated. But then this makes me suspicious of the solutions provided by sympy

Comment: @NameOfTheRose You shouldn't have to implement your own quartic formula. That's what sympy is for :P. There is no zerodivision error but rather only `oo` and `nan`. `nan` does show up if you substitute `c` first and then `b`. Just note with computer algebra systems that they can't add a piecewise for every possibility and they have to make things such as `x/x == 1` in all cases. This is likely a similar case. I advise substituting before solving or going with @Oscar-Benjamin's advice.

Comment: A better solution than adding a Piecewise for every possibility would be for `solveset` to return a kind of `RootSet` object that represents the roots of a polynomial. Then after substituting it can produce an appropriate formula. The quadratic formula is usually too complicated to be of much use anyway.

Comment: @Maelstrom,@oscar-benjamin, thank you for your remarks and suggestions. You have answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the remarks and insights presented by @Maelstrom and @Oscar-Benjamin in the above comments, the answer given by sympy is the one quoted in the literature as the general formula for a quatric equation. But this formula is valid subject to conditions that are complicated functions of the polynomial coefficients. The answer returned by sympy does not include these conditions. I do not doubt that there are good reasons that sympy does so, nevertheless the answer is, in my opinion, unusable.

It so happens that `b=0,c=-1` violate these conditions and the general formula evaluates to numbers that are not roots.

From a practical point, one should first substitute the actual values to the polynomial and then solve for its roots.